# New instance of model does not include List<T> property

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

Model:

```
    public int SelectedPersonId { get; set; }
    List<tblRecipActivity> PersonActivites { get; set; }
```

In controller I try to populate the list but it says the model does not contain a property called PersonActivities.

Controller:

```
Person model = new Person();
model.PersonActivities = repo.GetPersonActivitiesList();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It needs to be public i.e.

```
public List<tblRecipActivity> PersonActivites { get; set; }
```